# Maintaining log file using `log4j` api in java

Tags: java, log4j

I am using `log4j` api to maintain log of my application. I used following while initializing the `private Logger logger;`

```
logger = Logger.getLogger("Application Started ");
```

But it displays `Application Started` in every action like following :

```
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 11:50:41,140] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 11:50:33 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:248)- SMSC Setup Panel opened.
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:15,423] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19   12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:247)- 
SMSC Setup Panel opened.
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:17,576] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:264)- 
Key messaage setup panel opened.
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:19,713] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:282)- 
Binding details panel opened
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:21,850] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:353)- 
Key Message Details Panel opened
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:23,093] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:371)- 
Blocked Smsc Details panel opened.
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 12:00:24,575] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started at Mon Aug 19 12:00:08 NPT 2013 (SMSCMainFrame.java:335)- 
Request response report panel opened.
```

I want to display `Application started` message only one time when my application starts.

**Like :**

```
[ INFO] [2013-08-19 11:50:41,140] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started...
```

then only other logs should be display in my log file.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `getLogger` is the *name* of the logger; you're telling it to call the logger `Application Started`. Instead, it's usually best to use your class name (for example, `Logger.getLogger(ThisClass.class)`). What you're trying to do is simply write a log message with the content "Application started", so do that at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need provide more code snippet, showing how the `logger` is invoked, like:

```
logger.info("SMSC Setup Panel opened.");
```

Basically, every time you call a `logger.info("")`, there will be a log item in your log file, if the log level is set to `INFO`.

To just show one item like:

> [ INFO] [2013-08-19 11:50:41,140] AWT-EventQueue-0 Application Started...

you can set your log level to `INFO`, and call logger in following way:

```
logger.info("application started");
....
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("xxxxxx");
```